# Java Runnables start running before they are called

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have a function whose output is processed by multiple threads (created after the function call occurs). But when I run the program I receive a NullPointerException from the thread before the function is finished running. How do I specify for Java not to start the threads early?

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {
    public MainClass() {
    ...
    myRunnable1 = new myRunnable(args[]);
    myRunnable2 = new myRunnable(args[]);
    ...
    }
    public void run() {
        for (someNumberOfRuns) {
            function1();
            System.out.println("Done");
            thread1 = new Thread(myRunnable);
            thread2 = new Thread(myRunnable);
            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            ...
        }
     }
}
```

On the first iteration through the for loop, both thread1 and thread2 will throw NullPointException errors, then the system will print out "Done". Does anyone know why the two threads are starting before their respective start() calls in the method?
Thanks.
(Java version is 1.6u26)

Comment: Please post actual _relevant_ code and an example of how you run it, ie. with arguments.

Comment: > "for (someNumberOfRuns) {"
Doesn't parse as Java code. Please, try again.

Comment: Don't extend Thread, instead you should implement Runnable to avoid confusion.  Can you post real code which compiles and demonstrates the problem?

Comment: And feedback on my answer.  Remember to accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know why the two threads are starting before their respective start() calls in the method?

This does not happen under Java -- if the thread is being started then some code is starting it.  I suspect that you are either calling the `run()` method directly in the thread that instantiates `MainThread` or you are calling `start()` in some place that you aren't expecting.

It may help if you [use a debugger](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) and put a breakpoint in the `run()` method to see who is calling it.  If you want to use `println` debugging you could print out an exception that shows the stack trace inside of `run()`:

```
new Throwable().printStackTrace();
```

If you provide the code that actually instantiates the `MainThread` we may be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to make a bunch of threads all wait to be started at the same time,

Have each thread execute a Runnable, and have the first line of run() be

```
barrier.await(LONG_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

where barrier is defined as

```
final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(numThreads + 1);
```

Then when you're ready for all of them to start, call

```
// Wait for all threads to be ready, then start them all at once
barrier.await(LONG_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

A timeout indicates that one of your threads did not execute withing the given time.